# disable error popup in visual studio

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2012, popup, runtime-error

I keep getting the following error in visual studio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKyk8.png

However if I click continue my application runs perfectly fine, every time I run it it does this. As you can imagine this is incredibly annoying. I have gone through the exception settings to try and find something under runtime, error, runtime_error, std and so on. I was not able to find anything that matched the description of the error. Additionally I have no idea what is causing this to popup in the first place, as how am I supposed to know what is using that memory location?

Comment: Use the debugger.  Your application is throwing an exception, you should find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to exception settings, add new C++ exception: std::runtime_error and uncheck it. Or just stop breaking in any C++ exceptions at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable it by properly handling the cause of the exception being thrown.  Debug your code to find what is causing the exception.